# Laravel testing chained jobs - assertion fails when using onQueue

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 10 and recently developed chunked download feature which takes advantage of Laravel's chained jobs. The feature creates several jobs based on chunk size and number of items to download and runs one job in the end to notify the user.

```
$jobChain = [];
foreach ($listIds as $listId) {
    $chunkCount = $count > self::BATCH_SIZE ? ceil($count / self::CHUNK_SIZE) : 1;
    $offset = 0;
    $limit = self::CHUNK_SIZE;
    for ($i = 0; $i < $chunkCount; $i++) {
       $jobChain[] = new DownloadJob($import, $listId, $accessToken, $apiEndpoint, $limit, $offset);
       $limit += self::CHUNK_SIZE;
       $offset += self::CHUNK_SIZE;
   }
}

$jobChain[] = new NotificationJob($this->import, $this->user, 'success');

Bus::chain($jobChain)->onQueue($queueName)->dispatch();
```

The feature works well but trying to test cover it is a hair-pulling experience. I eventually ended up with the following test which fails

```
Bus::fake();
Bus::assertChained([
            new DownloadJob($import, $lists[0], $accessToken, $apiEndpoint, 10000, 0),
            new DownloadJob($import, $lists[1], $accessToken, $apiEndpoint, 10000, 0),
            new NotificationJob($import, $this->user, 'success'),
        ]);
```

However, if I remove `onQueue` method in the actual dispatch and dispatch without specifying the queue

```
Bus::chain($jobChain)->dispatch();
```

the test is successful.

I could not find anywhere in `BusFake` to specify a queue on which chain is dispatched (for example, `QueueFake` has `assertPushedOn` method).

Could anyone advise? It's important to test the actual chain, not jobs separately.

Answer (score 0):

Testing chained jobs in Laravel using the Bus::fake() method can be tricky when you involve queues, especially if you specify the queue name using onQueue(). The Bus::fake() and the Queue::fake() work in slightly different ways, and sometimes, there can be inconsistencies in how they track dispatched jobs.

Here's how you can address this issue:

```
Using **Queue::fake()** instead of **Bus::fake()**:
Since you're dealing with queued jobs, it may be more appropriate to use Queue::fake(). This provides more specific methods for asserting about jobs on specific queues, like assertPushedOn().
```

```
Queue::fake();

// Trigger the chain
//...

Queue::assertPushedOn($queueName, DownloadJob::class);
Queue::assertPushedOn($queueName, NotificationJob::class);
```

**Manually Specifying Queue for Fake Jobs:**
When you're asserting chained jobs, manually specify the queue name on the jobs themselves. This is a bit of a workaround, but it can be effective:

```
Bus::fake();

// Trigger the chain
//...

Bus::assertChained([
    (new DownloadJob($import, $lists[0], $accessToken, $apiEndpoint, 10000, 0))->onQueue($queueName),
    (new DownloadJob($import, $lists[1], $accessToken, $apiEndpoint, 10000, 0))->onQueue($queueName),
    (new NotificationJob($import, $this->user, 'success'))->onQueue($queueName),
]);
```

```
**Testing Chained Jobs Individually:**
If you're unable to get the chained assertions to work in the way you expect, another approach is to test the logic of each individual job separately (which you might already be doing). Then, in the test for the chain, just ensure the jobs are dispatched in the expected order and let the individual job tests verify their own logic.

**Dive into the Laravel Source:**
When in doubt about how a particular feature works or doesn't work, diving into the Laravel source code itself can be enlightening. You can see how the Bus::fake() and Queue::fake() methods are implemented and maybe even come up with your own solution or fix.
```

Comment: I actually tried both approaches (and they both seem to work on paper) yet none of them worked unfortunately :(